# Can I merge two ceiling light fixtures into one with two wall switches?

Tags: electrical, electrical-distribution

I have two ceiling light fixtures on two separate wall switches that I would like to merge into one light fixture controlled by the two separate wall switches.   Do I just make one of the wall switches a three-way?  I am trying to avoid having to fish new wires if possible.

Comment: We need a bit more detail on the physical relationship between the current fixtures and info on the current wiring

Comment: That's likely not going to be possible unless you just get lucky. Going fishing is likely in your future.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I merge two ceiling light fixtures into one with two wall
>   switches?

To answer your first question, yes.  Almost all light fixtures have a white and black  wire for each individual socket.  Simply send one to each switch.

> Do I just make one of the wall switches a three-way?

Well you will need a "traveler" (extra wire) between the switches for a 3-way.  There are a couple of different ways to wire a 3-way here but if your walls are closed and you don't want to open them then the answer is, no.

Comment: And note that both switches have to be changed to 3-way if the rest is okay.

Comment: Actually you would need two wires. Travelers come in pairs. So do the switches. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_switching

Answer (score 0):

there are some newer (expensive) 3 way switches that communicate without wiring a traveler , I used a set on a flat roof slab floor house that it would not work any other way. you can remove one of the switches to the light that will be your remote location.  tie the lights together then install the leviton rf switch set, as far as I know it is still working and that was almost 3 years ago (the remote switch will use the power at the location you disconnect the light. I think they were called anywhere , or anyplace  switches.